# How to set clock and video time in javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need a digital clock and a video on a page. When the clock hits the 35th second of each minute, the video should start.

For example, at the time of 21:00:35 a 15 second video clip starts playing. Once it reaches the end of the clip, it sits idol until 21:01:10. The same 15 second video clip starts playing again, then again at 21:01:45.

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23 
  var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59

  if (h < 10) {
    h = "0" + h;
  }
  
  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }
  
  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }

  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  document.getElementById('myClock').innerText = time;
  document.getElementById('myClock').textContent = time;

  setTimeout(showTime, 1);
}

showTime();
```

```html
<i>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="Myvid01.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
  </video>
</i>
```

Comment: Do you want the video to play at the 35th second of every minute (00:35, 01:35, 02:35, etc) or every 35 seconds (00:35, 01:10, 01:45, etc)?

Comment: your requirements are not clear you want the video to play on **the 15th second** of every minute, or **every 15th second** in a minute?

Comment: every 35th second for 15 seconds @MuhammadOmerAslam kindly help

Comment: yes i want to play every 35 seconds (00:35, 01:10, 01:45 etc) @MTCoster

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing to me so forgive me but if all you need is

> When the clock hits 35th second of every minute then the video should start.

you can just add an id to your video

```
<video id="player" width="320" height="240" controls>
```

and add play() to your function if s = 35

```
if (s === 35 ) {
    player.play();
}
```